# Who is said to do Work, me or the body?

Tags: forces, soft-question, terminology, work, definition

If I subject my force to a body and it is displaced then the work is said to be done. What is that work done by? Is it said to be done by me or that body?

Comment: Which do you think?

Comment: I think, "by the body".

Comment: @KyleKanos I think it be like because  A striking hammer is said to do work itself however it is always striked by a Human or machine's force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the correct way to think about it but this is my reasoning if you applied force on the body you had to spend the energy to do that work therefore you did the work the body gained the energy in some form say you lifted it of the ground the body has gained potential energy while you lost some bio-mechanical energy.

Comment: It must have been a comment. Don't it?

Comment: if it helps in answering your question no if it is just additional info yes

Comment: It's OK! I have no problem..

Comment: just think about the logic who spent the energy even as you said the hammer had to be wielded by a human or machine and that machine or human had to use energy to do it so it ia said that the work was done by the human or machine

Comment: Then, what is the case in which we say that work is done by body?

Answer (score 1):

For your case work is done by the one who applies force and displaces an object in any direction. You take this example "if an object falls from a height then the work is done by gravity (look who is applying force here )" I hope u understood it .
 Work cannot be done by a body who does not have it's own energy source like an hammer can never do work.

Answer (score 0):

If you exert a force on a body and it becomes displaced, then *it is said that* work is done by you or, by the force on that body.

Comment: But in my textbook, there is written that " If a body is moving with velocity "V" of mass "m" from position A to B and covers a distance "S" then Work done by that body is given by... $W=F\times{S}\times{cos}\theta$" There is not mentioned that how body moving but I assume that there must be a external force for that process and it can be my Force.

Comment: Are you confirmed at your statement or is it just an opinion? A striking hammer is said to do work itself however it is always striked by a Human or machine's force.

Comment: I have edited the answer a bit.

Comment: Yes I see but no change indeed. Work is said to be done by my force or we can say by me.

Comment: Is it never said to be done by body being displaced irrespective of force?

Comment: No. However, it is basically a definition.

Comment: What do you say about my textbook?

Comment: What do you say about the example of hammer given in my textbook?

Comment: Which textbook are you following?

Comment: General Physics - Henry Crew

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, if a body is moved from a point to another by some force, it is said that the force does some work on the body.